# Remove Verdaccio https redirect

Tags: verdaccio

For our local verdaccio instance i setup https. Unfortunately there are complications with our self signed cert and other programs.

So i tried to revert that and serve verdaccio over http again.

I changed the config.yaml back to it's original state, but unfortunetly i still get redirected to https with a 307 Internal Redirect.

How can i disable this redirect, so my verdaccio instance is reachable via http again?

Here is my current config.yaml:

```
#
# This is the default config file. It allows all users to do anything,
# so don't use it on production systems.
#
# Look here for more config file examples:
# https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/tree/master/conf
#

# path to a directory with all packages
storage: /home/lukas/.local/share/verdaccio/storage
# path to a directory with plugins to include
plugins: ./plugins

web:
  title: Verdaccio
  # comment out to disable gravatar support
  # gravatar: false
  # by default packages are ordercer ascendant (asc|desc)
  # sort_packages: asc

auth:
  htpasswd:
    file: ./htpasswd
    # Maximum amount of users allowed to register, defaults to "+inf".
    # You can set this to -1 to disable registration.
    # max_users: 1000

# a list of other known repositories we can talk to
uplinks:
  npmjs:
    url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

packages:
  '@*/*':
    # scoped packages
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    unpublish: $authenticated
    proxy: npmjs

  '**':
    # allow all users (including non-authenticated users) to read and
    # publish all packages
    #
    # you can specify usernames/groupnames (depending on your auth plugin)
    # and three keywords: "$all", "$anonymous", "$authenticated"
    access: $all

    # allow all known users to publish/publish packages
    # (anyone can register by default, remember?)
    publish: $authenticated
    unpublish: $authenticated

    # if package is not available locally, proxy requests to 'npmjs' registry
    proxy: npmjs

# You can specify HTTP/1.1 server keep alive timeout in seconds for incoming connections.
# A value of 0 makes the http server behave similarly to Node.js versions prior to 8.0.0, which did not have a keep-alive timeout.
# WORKAROUND: Through given configuration you can workaround following issue https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio/issues/301. Set to 0 in case 60 is not en$server:
  keepAliveTimeout: 60

middlewares:
  audit:
    enabled: true

# log settings
logs:
  - { type: stdout, format: pretty, level: http }
  #- {type: file, path: verdaccio.log, level: info}
#experiments:
#  # support for npm token command
#  token: false
listen: http://0.0.0.0:4873

#https:
#  key: /home/lukas/.config/verdaccio/verdaccio-key.pem
#  cert: /home/lukas/.config/verdaccio/verdaccio-cert.pem
#  ca: /home/lukas/.config/verdaccio/verdaccio-csr.pem

max_body_size: 250mb
```

**EDIT:**

For completeness. I also have installed GitLab EE on this server which is served via https and has a redirect configured (https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#redirect-http-requests-to-https)

The two webservers shouldn't interfere each other as verdaccio is running on port 4873 and gitlab on 80/443.

Comment: The config you have posted should do that. Sorry for the dumb questions but 1) Are you sure you edited the correct file? 2) Have you restarted verdaccio after you edited the file?  Try setting a different port (just for testing purposes) to check if the changed config is actually in place ...

Comment: Do you have any proxy for accessing verdaccio? Because I never saw verdaccio doing a redirect from HTTP -> HTTPS ...

Comment: @derpirscher I did try restarting and changing port. I edited my question because i also have gitlab installed on the server. Although they shouldn't interfere with each other. But i could be wrong here.

Comment: No, gitlab and verdaccio should not interfere. So when you changed the port from 4873 to say 4874, you were able to connect to verdaccio at port 4874 but still got redirected to https://? Are you trying to connect via browser or via `npm` command in the console? Have you looked in your local `.npmrc` what is the url for your local registry?

Comment: Yes if i change to port 4874 i still get the redirect to https://. Im testing with chrome. The domain is gitlab.example.com which we gave a local DNS Entry to point at our linux machine. Not sure what you mean with .npmrc

Comment: `.npmrc` is the settings file, which is used by the `npm` command (for instance to store the default registry to connect to when you do `npm install`) Still not sure, there isn't some proxy involved, because verdaccio doesn't usually redirect to https. It's either configured to listen on https or http and sticks with it.

Comment: Hmm i think you're right with the proxy. I just tried connecting to it via ip and that works!